# How to Disable HDR video for Instagram Reels on ANDROID

Tags: settings, hdr

How can I disable HDR videos on Instagram reels, and perhaps more generally how can i disable Instagram reels on specific apps. I am aware there is an option for [iPhone's under Media Settings](https://twitter.com/jonah_manzano/status/1692008264236683611?lang=en), but this option does not show on my Android 14 phone (I am using S24 ultra).

Comment: "*disable Instagram reels on specific apps.*" did you mean "disable HDR video"?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant how can I disable HDR videos on Instagram reels